# codeigniter routing not working for single view page also

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have single controller and one view page when i try to load this view page using controller I am getting 404 error even route has set.

Controller:

```
class Navigation extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('header');

    }

}
```

In the view directory i had place a file with the name of header and it contains as "Test Navigation" in body that's it.

Routing file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['menu'] = 'Navigation';
```

This CI script placed under directory of books. So when i type as localhost/books/index.php/menu , I am getting 404 error. Please explain how to solve this.

Comment: Your controller name same as Class name ? Are you put your controller under sub folder ?

Comment: 1. No I have copied CI script into books folder, and  I didn't change controller or anything from respective locations.

Comment: Controller class name is Navigation

Comment: What is the file name of this `Navigation` controller ? is it Navigation.php ? or you just modified welcome controller and change class name from `Welcome` to `Navigation` ?

Comment: Navigation controller file name is category.php

Comment: oh god thank you Nucleo I made wrong file name, with your question I solved it.

Comment: Then change it to `Navigation.php`. Controller class name & filename should be match.

Comment: No problem, good you solved it. I will add answer if you wouldnt mind to accept ?

Comment: how to accept your answer here not showing accept answer button

Comment: Not sure, usually is check mark appear beside of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance. Good luck with your CI work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller class name & controller filename should be same. class `Navigation` should be under `Navigation.php`.

Note: This rules applied for the Model too.